# texturing ExtrudeGeometry

Tags: three.js, textures

I have a problem when I am drawing a canvas texture in THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.
The following image is what I want

[image]

But it seems to not work well. It appears a black scene. 
This is my project scene.The Texture is work fine to left PlaneGeometry, but no work well to right ExtrudeGeometry.

[image]

```
var shape = new THREE.Shape(points);

var extrudeSettings = { 
    size: 1, 
    amount: 8, 
    bevelEnabled: false, 
    material: 0, 
    extrudeMaterial: 1 
}; 

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrudeSettings);

var canvas = document.querySelector('.heatmap-canvas'); 

var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas); 

texture.needsUpdate = true; 

texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter; 

var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ 
    map: texture, 
    color: 0xffffff, 
    transparent: true, 
    opacity: 0.7 
}); 

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

Comment: do you have a light in your scene?

Comment: Yes.I have.  Everything is ok in my scene. My problem is the canvas texture can't  work to ExtrudeGeometry, but work well to PlaneGeometry.